# Java Crashes after installing jre

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using mac 10.14. After I installed jre v11, I cannot start eclipse, and I cannot run "java -jar xxx.jar xxxx.ejb" which originally worked. I have tried to reinstall java and eclipse, but they didn't work at all. I found that eclipse will crash after I install e(fx)clipse.

## Error message of the command

```
Dungeon.b: javaFXAppThd.run encountered exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Dungeon.c.a(Unknown Source)
    at Dungeon.c.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:877)
    at Dungeon.c.a(Unknown Source)
    at Dungeon.c.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at Dungeon.b.run(Unknown Source)
```

## some of the Eclipse Log

```
!SESSION 2018-11-24 22:10:01.689 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.9.0.I20180906-0745
java.version=11.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=zh_HK_#Hant
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.committers.product -keyring /Users/manchingli/.eclipse_keyring
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.committers.product -keyring /Users/manchingli/.eclipse_keyring

!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core 4 0 2018-11-24 22:10:03.348
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core [293]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.xmlrpc
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.xmlrpc; bundle-version="3.0.0.v20100427-1100"
       org.apache.xmlrpc [72]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.xml.bind
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc; bundle-version="[3.8.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc; bundle-version="3.24.2.v20180904-2231"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc [309]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.xmlrpc; bundle-version="[3.0.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.xmlrpc; bundle-version="3.0.0.v20100427-1100"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1685)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1664)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1627)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1558)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:343)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.ui 4 0 2018-11-24 22:10:03.349
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.ui [294]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core; bundle-version="[3.8.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core; bundle-version="3.24.2.v20180905-0003"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core [293]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.xmlrpc
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.xmlrpc; bundle-version="3.0.0.v20100427-1100"
              org.apache.xmlrpc [72]
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.xml.bind
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc; bundle-version="[3.8.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc; bundle-version="3.24.2.v20180904-2231"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc [309]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.xmlrpc; bundle-version="[3.0.0,4.0.0)"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.xmlrpc; bundle-version="3.0.0.v20100427-1100"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1685)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1664)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1627)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1558)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:343)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc 4 0 2018-11-24 22:10:03.349
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc [309]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.xmlrpc; bundle-version="[3.0.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.xmlrpc; bundle-version="3.0.0.v20100427-1100"
       org.apache.xmlrpc [72]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.xml.bind

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1685)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1664)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1627)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1558)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:343)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2018-11-24 22:10:09.569
!MESSAGE System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.monitoring 4 0 2018-11-24 22:10:31.160
!MESSAGE UI freeze of 3.0s at 22:10:28.168
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui.monitoring 1 0 2018-11-24 22:10:31.160
!MESSAGE Sample at 22:10:28.944 (+0.776s)
Thread 'main' tid=1 (RUNNABLE)
!STACK 0
Stack Trace
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.expression.Member$DynamicMember.invoke(Member.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.expression.Member$DynamicMember.evaluate(Member.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.expression.Equals.evaluate(Equals.java:32)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.expression.And.evaluate(And.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.expression.Unary.evaluate(Unary.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.expression.Exists.evaluate(Exists.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.expression.CollectionFilter.evaluate(CollectionFilter.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.expression.MatchExpression.isMatch(MatchExpression.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.expression.MatchExpression.isMatch(MatchExpression.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.Requirement.isMatch(Requirement.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.InstallableUnit.satisfies(InstallableUnit.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.expression.Matches.match(Matches.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.expression.Matches.evaluate(Matches.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.expression.Unary.evaluate(Unary.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.expression.Exists.evaluate(Exists.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.expression.CollectionFilter.evaluate(CollectionFilter.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.expression.Unary.evaluate(Unary.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.expression.Latest.evaluateAsIterator(Latest.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.expression.ContextExpression.iterator(ContextExpression.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.query.ExpressionQuery.perform(ExpressionQuery.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.index.IndexProvider.query(IndexProvider.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.index.IndexProvider.query(IndexProvider.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.QueryableRepositoryManager.query(QueryableRepositoryManager.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.QueryableRepositoryManager.query(QueryableRepositoryManager.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.ElementQueryDescriptor.performQuery(ElementQueryDescriptor.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.model.QueriedElement.fetchChildren(QueriedElement.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.model.CategoryElement.fetchChildren(CategoryElement.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.model.QueriedElement.getChildren(QueriedElement.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.viewers.DeferredQueryContentProvider.getChildren(DeferredQueryContentProvider.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PatternFilter.isParentMatch(PatternFilter.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.dialogs.AvailableIUPatternFilter.isParentMatch(AvailableIUPatternFilter.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PatternFilter.isElementVisible(PatternFilter.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PatternFilter.select(PatternFilter.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerFilter.filter(ViewerFilter.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PatternFilter.filter(PatternFilter.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.getFilteredChildren(StructuredViewer.java:907)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.getSortedChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:621)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.updateChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalRefreshStruct(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1953)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.internalRefreshStruct(TreeViewer.java:677)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1929)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1886)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.dialogs.ContainerCheckedTreeViewer.internalRefresh(ContainerCheckedTreeViewer.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.lambda$3(StructuredViewer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$$Lambda$381/0x0000000800939c40.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1449)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.preservingSelection(TreeViewer.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.CheckboxTreeViewer.preservingSelection(CheckboxTreeViewer.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.dialogs.ContainerCheckedTreeViewer.preservingSelection(ContainerCheckedTreeViewer.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.refresh(StructuredViewer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.refresh(ColumnViewer.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.refresh(StructuredViewer.java:1494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.FilteredTree$1.runInUIThread(FilteredTree.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob.lambda$0(UIJob.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$$Lambda$460/0x0000000800b0d440.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4068)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3735)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:821)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:797)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.ProvisioningUI.openInstallWizard(ProvisioningUI.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.ProvisioningUI.openInstallWizard(ProvisioningUI.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.InstallNewSoftwareHandler.doExecute(InstallNewSoftwareHandler.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.PreloadingRepositoryHandler.doExecuteAndLoad(PreloadingRepositoryHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.PreloadingRepositoryHandler.lambda$0(PreloadingRepositoryHandler.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.PreloadingRepositoryHandler$$Lambda$522/0x0000000800cf2c40.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.PreloadingRepositoryHandler.execute(PreloadingRepositoryHandler.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.InstallNewSoftwareHandler.execute(InstallNewSoftwareHandler.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:96)
    at java.base@11.0.1/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@11.0.1/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base@11.0.1/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@11.0.1/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:436)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(AbstractContributionItem.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem.lambda$2(AbstractContributionItem.java:475)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem$$Lambda$277/0x00000008007d9040.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4292)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1512)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1535)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1520)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1324)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4116)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3733)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$$Lambda$118/0x0000000800408440.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:246)
    at java.base@11.0.1/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@11.0.1/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base@11.0.1/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@11.0.1/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at app//org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at app//org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:595)
    at app//org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1501)
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.monitoring 1 0 2018-11-24 22:10:31.160
!MESSAGE Thread 'Common-Cleaner' tid=9 (TIMED_WAITING)
Waiting for: java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@2210e1f3
!STACK 0
Stack Trace
    at java.base@11.0.1/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.base@11.0.1/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:155)
    at java.base@11.0.1/jdk.internal.ref.CleanerImpl.run(CleanerImpl.java:148)
    at java.base@11.0.1/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at java.base@11.0.1/jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread.run(InnocuousThread.java:134)
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.monitoring 1 0 2018-11-24 22:10:31.161
!MESSAGE Thread 'Active Thread: Equinox Container: 0d101a18-e145-4d53-b229-a088c6ba3375' tid=14 (TIMED_WAITING)
Waiting for: java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@35bb6831
!STACK 0
Stack Trace
    at java.base@11.0.1/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.base@11.0.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
    at java.base@11.0.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2123)
    at java.base@11.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
    at java.base@11.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
    at java.base@11.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
    at java.base@11.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
    at java.base@11.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base@11.0.1/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: It seems that you have two different problems here. Please raise one problem per question.

Comment: Which Eclipse e(fx)clipse version did you install? JavaFX has been removed in Java 11 and therefore [Eclipse e(fx)clipse 3.4](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.efxclipse/reviews/3.4.0-release-review) or higher is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your JAVA_HOME that it is pointing to where you want it to point to, and have your path pointing to the same location. It looks very much that you are in this way mixing up to Java versions. Also restart you machine so that you are sure that it is still okay after a restart

Comment: I found the problem was that the path and the version I was using were not matched. Fixed. thanks a lot